# Check group of millions using javascript

Tags: javascript

Here I'm returning an array with values in which is formatted as such

```
var myObj = {
    "account": "5622555",
    "account1": "156726",
    "account3": "889338",
    etc....
}
```

I'm then formatting this array and assigning the values to a **HTML** div, here's the code I'm using.

```
$.each(myObj, function(index, value){
    $("#account" + index).html(value);
});
```

How can I change the `value` to display in groups of millions etc.. like so

```
if(value > 1000000) {
    if(value < 2000000) {
        if(value != 1000000) {
            $("#account" + index).html("1M+");
        } else {
            $("#account" + index).html("1M");
        }
    }
}
if(value > 2000000) {
    if(value < 3000000) {
        if(value != 2000000) {
            $("#account" + index).html("2M+");
        } else {
            $("#account" + index).html("2M");
        }
    }
}
if(value > 3000000) {
    if(value < 4000000) {
        if(value != 3000000) {
            $("#account" + index).html("3M+");
        } else {
            $("#account" + index).html("3M");
        }
    }
}
```

What's a quicker way of performing such `if` statements so I don't have to write the complete number?

Comment: Covert the number into a string and than replace `000000` with `M+` ? :P

Comment: Keep in mind, that since a `value` will never validate if it is exactly 1000000, 2000000, or 3000000, you will never see 1M, 2M or 3M. `>=` will correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be

```
$.each(myObj, function(index, value){
    if(value > 999999) 
        $("#account" + index).html(String.prototype.replace.call(value, /(\d)(\d{6})/, "$1" + (value%1000000 > 0 ? 'M+' : 'M'), 'g'));
    else
        $("#account" + index).html(value);
});
```

Comment: @Curtis, what about the numbers that aren't above 1 million? This code just leaves the entry blank.

Comment: @Andy you're right, this should be wrapped in an `if(value > 999999)`

Comment: @Curtis There's was also a little bug, please update your code with this new version

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = 1000000;
    for(i = 1; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
    if(value > i*x && value < (i+1)*x)
    $("#account" + index).html(i+"M+");
    }
```

Follow the same pattern if you wanna take it to billions

Answer (score 0):

How about starting your comparisons from high to low, starting with the largest value that you'll be expecting, like so:

```
if (value > 3000000)
    $("#account" + index).html("3M+");
else if (Value > 2000000)
    $("#account" + index).html("2M+");
else if (Value > 1000000)
    $("#account" + index).html("1M+");
else if (Value = 1000000)
    $("#account" + index).html("1M");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(myObj, function(index, value) {
  var check = parseInt(value / 1000000, 10);
  if (check > 0) {
    $("#account" + index).html(check + 'M+');
  } else {
    $("#account" + index).html(value);
  }
});
```

Will produce: 5M, 156726, 889338.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/NYFjM/)

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
if(value = 1000000)
    $("#account" + index).html("1M");
if(value > 1000000 && value < 2000000) {
    $("#account" + index).html("1M+");
}
```

This looks cleaner. Another option is to declare constants so oneM = 1000000, twoM = 2000000 then you just reference those variables